# Match Variable Count of Repeating Words

Tags: regex

(I am stepping through this laboriously to get my thoughts in order. Skip to the end for the question!)

My input (file names) is like this

```
word1.word2.word3.e01S01.word4.word5.ext
word1.word2.E03s04.word3.ext
word1.e24s02.ext
```

(Any number of words can be before or after ExxSxx; xx is 00-99, E and S are constants but may be uppercase or lowercase; there's always ext but it's variable alpha.)

My desired output for these examples:

```
Word1 Word2 Word3 E01S01.ext
Word1 Word2 E03S04.ext
Word1 E24S02.ext
```

(All words before and including ExxSxx are kept; . is replaced with space; words are in title case; E and S are capitalised; words between ExxSxx and .ext are discarded; ext is appended unchanged.)

I can match a *known* number of repeats (here 2) between . with this regex (match 1 or more instances of not . up to a dot):

```
[^\.]+\.
```

and I can group like this to be able to refer to what I want to extract:

```
^([^\.]+)\.                so \u$1 gives Word1
```

I can repeat 2 times:

```
^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.      so \u$1 \u$2 gives Word1 Word2
```

I can continue:

```
^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([eE][0-9]{2}[sS][0-9]{2})
                          so \u$1 \u$2 \U$3 gives Word1 Word2 ExxSxx
```

Then I skip over the remainder and grab .ext:

```
^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([eE][0-9]{2}[sS][0-9]{2}).*(\.[a-z]{3}$)
                          so \u$1 \u$2 \U$3\L$4 gives Word1 Word2 ExxSxx.ext
```

Here, finally, is my question:

Without explicitly repeating the pattern for the first x words can I get what I want with any number of .-separated words?  Would it be better to grab everything up to and including the known ExxSxx together with .ext and deal with capitalisation afterwards?

Comment: Is it Notepad++ regex?

Comment: Not particularly. I am looking at the principle rather than a specific flavour.

Comment: Good luck then. Without the regex flavor, this question is unclear.

Comment: Your last example should be `Word1.E24S02.ext`, I think

Comment: If you are referring to input example, then my text is correct. E and S can be uppercase or lowercase

Comment: No, there should (maybe) be a `.` between `Word1` and `E24S02`

Comment: If you are referring to input example, then there is one.  Because you are capitalising, I guess you are looking at the desired output.  My text says '. is replaced with space'

Comment: But then why do the other examples have a `.` there? Such as `Word1 Word2.E03S04.ext`? What is different about that one? Shouldn't it be `Word1 Word2 E03S04.ext` if that's really the case?

Comment: Oh I see!  You are right, but it's the other examples that have the error.  I'll edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh man, that was a hard one. You cannot do it with one piece of regex capturing a whole line at a time as far a I'm aware (unfortunately), but you can handle it piece by piece if you do something like this:

```
(?:([eE]\d\d[sS]\d\d).*(\.ext)|\b(\w)([^.]*)\.)
```

Explanation:

```
(?:                                              // -Case 1- (non-capturing group)
   ([eE]\d\d[sS]\d\d)                            // Capture the e01S01 bit as \1
                     .*                          // Anything at all up until...
                       (\.ext)                   // ... The extension! (Capture as \2)
                              |                  // -Case 2-
                               \b(\w)            // Word boundary, then a word character (Capture as \3)
                                     ([^.]*)     // The rest of the word (Capture as \4)
                                            \.)  // The dot
```

And replace with this:

```
\U\3\L\4\U\1\L\2 \E
```

Explanation:

```
\U\3                  // (Case 2) Uppercase the first letter of the first word
    \L\4              // Lowercase the rest of the word
        \U\1          // (Case 1) Uppercase the E01S01 bit.
            \L\2 \E   // Lowercase the extension, add a space, and end the enforced case (for good measure)
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/oHpXXS/3

Basically it'll go through and resolve each part, piece by piece, until it's done with the whole thing. Only 2 of the 4 capturing groups will ever be used - `\3` and `\4` in case 1, or `\1` and `\2` in case 2. The other capturing groups will be blank, and therefore resolve to nothing.

#### Problems:

This has a trailing space at the end of every single entry. No ideas for how to make it go away.

Comment: Thank you.  The trailing space doesn't matter and I could trim it away if needed.